# carrierwave process uploaded file in a custom way

Tags: process, carrierwave

I want to do the following:

- convert the uploaded file to jpeg2000 using the command kdu_compress
- not use rmagick or minimagick to do this stuff

All examples in carrierwave are using rmagick or minimagick, and act on a in memory loaded image file. So I don't really know how to convert something using a custom shell command and report the changed filename  back to carrierwave.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you found a solution to run Shell and return to carrierwave?